# Firebase Auth with Google using signInWithPopup only works on mobile not on desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin

in creating a project with React and Im currently trying to create a login using Firebase with Google and signInWithPopup, but when I touch the button to trigger the popup, the popup shows but blank, but with the correct URL

[image: PopUp Screen Image]

When I do the same on mobile, its make the redirect and choose my account.
Also all the rest of the Firebase features works

This is the code for the `signInWithPopUp`

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
var provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  return signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
}
```

And this is the code for the login page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../Firebase";

const Login = () => {

    function InitWithGoogle() {
        signInWithGoogle();
    }

    return (
           <button type="button" onClick={InitWithGoogle} className="login-with-google-btn" >Sign in with Google</button>

    )
}

export default Login
```

Also this is the errors I get on console:

[image: Console error messages image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a function

```
function InitWithGoogle() {
        signInWithGoogle();
    }
```

once you have imported your signinwithGoogle function use it inside of your button

```
<button onClick={()=>signInwithGoogle}
```

Comment: Its works, thanks! just a note in added like this:
`<button onClick={()=>signInWithGoogle()}`

Comment: For some reason again its not working, the button is exactly as the comment above and the signInWithGoogle funcion is like this: 
`export const signInWithGoogle = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);`

Comment: No you should just pass the name don't put parenthesis. If this works feel free to mark ans as  correct . You can do that by clicking on tick below my votes